# Monitor SSD read/write activity on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd, logging, monitoring

I read on http://www.outsidethebox.ms/why-windows-8-defragments-your-ssd-and-how-you-can-avoid-this/ that windows scheduled defragmentation may accidentally defragment the SSD drives because of a suspected bug. Is there a way to log the daily SSD read/write to check whether this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows only [defrags the SSD when Volume Snapshots are enabled](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheRealAndCompleteStoryDoesWindowsDefragmentYourSSD.aspx):

> Storage Optimizer will defrag an SSD once a month if volume snapshots
>   are enabled. This is by design and necessary due to slow volsnap copy
>   on write performance on fragmented SSD volumes. It’s also somewhat of
>   a misconception that fragmentation is not a problem on SSDs. If an SSD
>   gets too fragmented you can hit maximum file fragmentation (when the
>   metadata can’t represent any more file fragments) which will result in
>   errors when you try to write/extend a file. Furthermore, more file
>   fragments means more metadata to process while reading/writing a file,
>   which can lead to slower performance.
>
> As far as Retrim is concerned, this command should run on the schedule
>   specified in the dfrgui UI. Retrim is necessary because of the way
>   TRIM is processed in the file systems. Due to the varying performance
>   of hardware responding to TRIM, TRIM is processed asynchronously by
>   the file system. When a file is deleted or space is otherwise freed,
>   the file system queues the trim request to be processed. To limit the
>   peek resource usage this queue may only grow to a maximum number of
>   trim requests. If the queue is of max size, incoming TRIM requests may
>   be dropped. This is okay because we will periodically come through and
>   do a Retrim with Storage Optimizer. The Retrim is done at a
>   granularity that should avoid hitting the maximum TRIM request queue
>   size where TRIMs are dropped.
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> No, Windows is not foolishly or blindly running a defrag on your SSD
>   every night, and no, ***Windows defrag isn't shortening the life of your
>   SSD unnecessarily***. Modern SSDs don't work the same way that we are
>   used to with traditional hard drives.
>
> Yes, your SSD's file system sometimes needs a kind of defragmentation
>   and that's handled by Windows, monthly by default, when appropriate.
>   The intent is to maximize performance and a long life. If you disable
>   defragmentation completely, you are taking a risk that your filesystem
>   metadata could reach maximum fragmentation and get you potentially in
>   trouble.

Comment: Okay, so I have to turn off volsnap to get rid of this unwanted "feature", which kills SSD. And the only cause that according to them fragmentation makes volsnap writing slower. Ridiculous...